# general understanding of packages and environments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a general misunderstanding of the concept of Python environments and am hoping to get clarification on a few questions here.

I use Python via Anaconda with Jupyter Notebook and have set up a few environments. But in the one or the other place a thinking error or something apparently made wrong.

Via anaconda prompt `activate base` I created a new environment `conda create -c conda-forge --name TEST_env python=3.6 anaconda`.
Afterwards selecting that via `activate TEST_env` and add a few libraries via `conda install geopandas`, `conda install plotly` etc. After that I registered the environment via `python -m ipykernel install --user --name TEST_env`.

If I then start jupyter notebook from the anaconda prompt and select TEST_env kernel and in a jupyter notebook I checked the call for geopandas:

```
import geopandas
print(geopandas.__file__)
```

it does not point to my environment folder `C:\Users\User01\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\TEST_env` - but to `C:\Users\User01\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py`.

Why is this the case? What did I forget or do wrong when setting up the environment?

Is there a possibility to adjust this retroactively or do I have to set up the environment again?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the record, ```conda install``` can probably be done in a single command if you separate each argument with a space (assuming ```conda install``` uses the same syntax as ```pip install```). 

[pip](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

[conda](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-up-virtual-environment-for-python-using-anaconda/)